# sapui5 how to read PDF file content in controller

Tags: sapui5

Im facing an issue in PDF File Uploading..

[image]

In the above Screenshot if you see, When im trying to upload a PDF file, Im not able to read the content in that pdf file.
My requirement is like, I need to get the content as **String** from that file and that content i need to send to back-end server..

Im getting below error if im trying to read the content

**HTTP Status 405 - Bad Method**[image]

Below is my Code ..

Im using **xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"** library

```
<u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" name="myFileUpload" tooltip="Upload Service Sheet"
                                                uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" change="handleValueChange" typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch" style="Emphasized" fileType="pdf"
                                                placeholder="Choose a file for Upload..." maximumFileSize="2000" mimeType="pdf" buttonText="Upload">
                                            </u:FileUploader>

handleUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
            var fileName = oEvent.getSource().getProperty("value");
            var sResponse = oEvent.getParameter("response");
            if (sResponse) {
                var sMsg = "";
                var m = /^\[(\d\d\d)\]:(.*)$/.exec(sResponse);
                if (m[0] == "200") {
                    sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[0] + "(Upload Success)";
                    oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
                } else {
                    sMsg = "Return Code: " + m[0] + "(Upload Error)";
                }

                MessageToast.show(sMsg);
            }

        },
```

Can some one please help me how can i read the data in the PDF??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this example. Hope this helps.

**View**

```
    <u:FileUploader change="onChange" fileType="pdf" mimeType="pdf" buttonText="Upload" />
```

**Controller**

```
    convertBinaryToHex: function(buffer) {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), function(x) {
            return ("00" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join("");
    },


    onChange: function(oEvent){
        var that = this;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var raw = e.target.result;
            var hexString = that.convertBinaryToHex(raw).toUpperCase(); 
            // DO YOUR THING HERE            
        };

        reader.onerror = function() {
            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error occured when uploading file");
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    },
```

Comment: Thank you Mennens, I have converted the ES6 code to JS

Comment: I changed it in my answer

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. This answer helped me alot..Thank you for your quick response